# PHP find base url

Tags: php

I have the following code

```
<a href="http://blown-away.org/biography/#donate" class="btn">Donate Now</a>
```

What I want to do with php is replace the absolute url part with php then just append `biography/#donate`
so basically generating the url so whatever page the user is on they get sent to `www.mysite.com/biography/#donate`

I have tried using  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` but just seems to add the link to the existing url

thanks in advance

Comment: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php

Comment: Why don't you just use `<a href="/biography/#donate" ...`

Comment: you might want to look at adding such a thing a environmental config so that when your on local or development or staging is all changes with you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];` instead

Answer (score 0):

In such cases i'm using the <[base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp)> tag in header.

```
<base href="http://myabsolute.host/or.subfolder/" />
```

Then i just use relative links to my anchors, which are resolved to my base url.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `parse_url` in my example. I hope this is what you're looking for:

```
<?php
$url = "http://blown-away.org/biography/#donate";
$mySiteHost = "mysite.com";
$parts = parse_url($url);
echo str_replace($parts["host"], $mySiteHost, $url)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'http://blown-away.org/biography/#donate';
echo "Original Url : " . $url . "</br></br>";
$tempArray = parse_url($url);
$tempArray['host'] = "www.mysite.com";

$tempUrlString = "";
foreach($tempArray as $key => $value){
    if($key == "scheme"){
        $tempUrlString = $tempUrlString . $value . "://";
    }else{
        $tempUrlString = $tempUrlString . $value;
    }
}

echo "Modified Url : " . $tempUrlString . "";
```